# how can I get the actual screen size when an application runs in compatibility mode

Tags: android, screen

I try to read the screen size by using DeviceMetrics, but it gives me the scaled size, not the actual screen size.

How can I read the actual screen size in compatibility mode?

For example, the application runs on a 480x800 screen.
But it gives me 400x700, because of the compatiblility mode.

Comment: which method are you using to retrieve the `DisplayMetrics`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        Point point= new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(point);
        screenWidth = point.x;
        screenHeight = point.y;
    } else {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    }
```

note: because of the method `getRealSize` you might need to catch `NoSuchMethodError` Exception